# How to manage a sequence in java without a DB?

Tags: java, spring, cxf

The scenario is as follows:

I'm using Apache CXF to expose web services to a client.
After receiving a request and processing it, I need to add a sequence number to the processed message header, and the I forward it to another program via MQ.
Also I use Spring to handle bean management and injection.

What's the best way to manage a sequence without using a DB (since installing a DB just for sequence management seems to have an enormous overhead and bloat).
If the solution is to use a file (a properties file?), how can I opt for consistency if any exception occurs?
Also I need the sequence to be consistent when multiple requests arrive simultaneously.

Comment: Does it have to be a sequence or would a unique id suffice?

Comment: do you have this criteria..if once a sequence number is assigned to one message header it should not be allocated to other message at any point in future...i think you can use AtomicLong given by artplasticka

Comment: It must be a sequence, meaning each value is the previous value + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything works within the same class loader, you could create a singleton with [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) private field.

Answer (score 1):

Since you will be forwarding with MQ, why not just the MQ sequencing mechanism rather than keeping track yourself?

If you want to keep track yourself, you should look into a (synchronized) singleton doling out numbers. And if you want to maintain the sequence after restarts you *will* need a persistence mechanism (although not necessarily a DB). I'm sure one could engineer an MQ queue to provide this service, although it would be wildly out of proportions ;-)

Thus, have a look at MQ sequencing first.

Cheers,

Comment: MQ sequencing requires the receiving application to be able to retreive the messages that are in a group. In my case this app is a black box, thus I don't know if it has such capabilities.

Comment: You state "...add a sequence number to the processed message header..." Are you not talking about an MQ message here? If not, how do you know your black box at the other end will understand a sequence ID in the message body/value object?

Comment: I do put a message on the MQ, and the black box knows how to read the sequence number I put in the message body. But I'm not sure it knows how to read the sequence put in the messages' MQ header.

Answer (score 1):

If that service has only one instance, a timestamp from `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which should be enough for the most cases. If you can use a string as identifier, I would suggest using a timestamp string, plus the time in nanos.
If you have multiple instances of the webservice serving at the same time, you will probably need a singelton counter:

```
private static long counter = 0;
private static synchronized long nextCounter() {
    return counter++;
}
```

(You need to check for overflows, of course)

Most of the time, I use a combination of both.